# PHP Link in echo

Tags: php, text, hyperlink, echo

I have the echo below and I need to link in it but I get an unexpected T_STRING on that line with the link and it says expecting ',' or ';'

The code is:

```
echo " You Are Now A User Of ClipBoy! 
       Drag the image below to your bookmarks bar for easy access to your site! 
       To get to your site go to 
       <a href"http://themacsplash.com/ClipBoy/userfiles/$myUser" target "_blank">
       http://themacsplash.com/ClipBoy/userfiles/$myUser</a>";
```

How would I fix this?

Comment: href=\"http://... don't forget the = between the attribute and its value

Comment: Its our friend Will who keeps asking the same questions...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Escape the double quotes in your string, like this `\"`

So it becomes:

```
echo " You Are Now A User Of ClipBoy! 
       Drag the image below to your bookmarks bar for easy access to your site! 
       To get to your site go to 
       <a href=\"http://themacsplash.com/ClipBoy/userfiles/$myUser\" target=\"_blank\">
       http://themacsplash.com/ClipBoy/userfiles/$myUser</a>";
```

Comment: Please could you do me a sample because I don't know where to put them. Thanks!

Comment: @Will Evans. I have given you a sample already! Besides, I am curious, are you really a programmer?

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape the `"` with `\"`

Comment: Please could you do me a sample because I don't know where to put them. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You must escape your double quotes

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
 echo ' You Are Now A User Of ClipBoy! Drag the image below to your bookmarks bar for easy access to your site! To get to your site go to <a href="http://themacsplash.com/ClipBoy/userfiles/'.$myUser.'" target="_blank">http://themacsplash.com/ClipBoy/userfiles/'.$myUser.'</a>';
```

or :

```
 echo " You Are Now A User Of ClipBoy! Drag the image below to your bookmarks bar for easy access to your site! To get to your site go to <a href=\"http://themacsplash.com/ClipBoy/userfiles/$myUser\" target=\"_blank\">http://themacsplash.com/ClipBoy/userfiles/$myUser</a>";
```